# CD45 as a microglial marker in Fluorescence-Activated Cell Sorting (FACS)

Tags: flow-cytometry, cell-sorting

I am reading this article: [Microglial cannabinoid receptor type 1 mediates social memory deficits in mice produced by adolescent THC exposure and 16p11.2 duplication](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-023-42276-5).

In Figure 1a, the authors are using Fluorescence-Activated Cell Sorting (FACS) and are identifying different cell types as follows: microglia (CD45$^+$CD11b$^+$TMEM119$^+$), astrocyte (ACSA-2$^+$), and neuron (NeuN$^+$).

[image]

My understanding is that the upper and lower panels indicate two different batches of cells. The upper panel shows neurons identified by the NeuN marker. At first I was thinking that because of this "microglia (CD45$^+$CD11b$^+$TMEM119$^+$)," that cells were selected from Q2 in the left lower panel and were further examined in the context of expressing TMEM119 and ACSA-2 to differentiate between microglia and astrocytes.

The problem I am running into with my interpretation is two-fold. Reading from [abcam](https://www.abcam.com/neuroscience/microglia-markers): "A combination of CD11b and CD45 labeling can be used to distinguish microglia from macrophages. Resting microglia are CD11b$^{hi}$, CD45$^{low}$, whereas macrophages are CD11b$^{hi}$, CD45$^{hi}$." This would seem to indicate that Q1 is the pool of microglia. As far as Q2, if it represents macrophages, why would there be a larger presence than the resident immune cell microglia?

The second issue with my interpretation is that I do not see any literature suggesting that astrocytes express CD11b or CD45. Any help here is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Regarding the abcam source, they also provide [this](https://www.abcam.com/neuroscience/an-overview-of-microglia-subtypes-and-markers) with references.

Edit2: "In order to confirm Cnr1 expression at the protein level, we used magnetic activated cell sorting (MACS) to isolate microglia-enriched CD11b$^+$ cells, ACSA-2$^+$ astrocytes, and remaining cells including neurons from the cerebral cortex of Cx3cr1$^{CreER/+}$;Cnr1$^{flox/flox}$ mice and littermate controls (Cx3cr1$^{CreER/+}$;Cnr1$^{+/+}$). We used this approach as it produces a higher cell yield than FACS with over 95% of collected CD11b$^{+}$ cells being microglia." I feel like this excerpt from the paper should help to provide some clarification to whoever answers this question.